# How can I retrieve the color in a Photoshop Fill Layer

Tags: javascript, colors, photoshop

I'm trying to write a script to automate the process of extracting the colors from a number of Fill Layers from a Photoshop file that we customize depending on the use.
The problem is there doesn't seem to be a way to **read** a Fill Layer's assigned color.

I've tried everything I could think of, but nothing has worked. This is the closest I've gotten so far:

In [this](http://www.ps-scripts.com/bb/viewtopic.php?t=842) forum I found a way to read swatches values and names. I've used a Scripting Listener plugin to record actions, but all I get is something like this when double clicking the Fill Layer thumbnail and hitting "Add to swatches":

```
var idMk = charIDToTypeID( "Mk  " );
var desc90 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref42 = new ActionReference();
    var idClrs = charIDToTypeID( "Clrs" );
    ref42.putClass( idClrs );
desc90.putReference( idnull, ref42 );
var idUsng = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );
    var desc91 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idNm = charIDToTypeID( "Nm  " );
    desc91.putString( idNm, """Swatch 3""" );
    var idClr = charIDToTypeID( "Clr " );
        var desc92 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idRd = charIDToTypeID( "Rd  " );
        desc92.putDouble( idRd, 229.000397 );
        var idGrn = charIDToTypeID( "Grn " );
        desc92.putDouble( idGrn, 137.001801 );
        var idBl = charIDToTypeID( "Bl  " );
        desc92.putDouble( idBl, 135.997925 );
    var idRGBC = charIDToTypeID( "RGBC" );
    desc91.putObject( idClr, idRGBC, desc92 );
var idClrs = charIDToTypeID( "Clrs" );
desc90.putObject( idUsng, idClrs, desc91 );
executeAction( idMk, desc90, DialogModes.NO );
```

That is, I get the specific values I'm picking at that time, but no way to implement this in a loop (that I can think of, at least).

Also, if I can find a way to make each Fill Layer color in turn the foreground color, then I know I can read that, but how do I get there? The eyedropper seems like an option, but I can't hink of a way to make it work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It was there all the time, I guess. In [the forum thread mentioned above](http://www.ps-scripts.com/bb/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1534&sid=491ce256288b6a4000b7696fac541c8d), it says:

> this is basically how adjustment layers work. There is an 'Adjs' list
>   which *usually* has one Adjustment object, in this case a
>   solidColorLayer. Inside of that is the color descriptors.

I was able to treat each fill layer as if it was an adjustment layer, and extract the color data from there:

```
//@include "C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC/Presets/Scripts/xlib/stdlib.js"

//Create CSV file to record palette
var skinColors = File ("c:/Skinpalette.txt");
if (skinColors.exists) {
    skinColors.remove();
}    
skinColors = new File ("c:/Skinpalette.txt");

//Function to extract color from Layer
function getAdjustmentLayerColor(doc, layer) { 
    var desc = Stdlib.getLayerDescriptor(doc, layer);
    var adjs = desc.getList(cTID('Adjs'));

    var clrDesc = adjs.getObjectValue(0);
    var color= clrDesc.getObjectValue(cTID('Clr '));

    var red = Math.round(color.getDouble(cTID('Rd  ')));
    var green = Math.round(color.getDouble(cTID('Grn ')));
    var blue = Math.round(color.getDouble(cTID('Bl  ')));

    var createdSolidColor = Stdlib.createRGBColor(red, green, blue);
    var createdRGBColor = createdSolidColor.rgb;
    return createdRGBColor.hexValue;
};

//Function to cycle through layers and output to external file
function getColors(layerNode) {    
    for (var i=0; i<layerNode.length; i++) {
        getColors(layerNode[i].layerSets);
        for(var layerIndex=0; layerIndex < layerNode[i].artLayers.length; layerIndex++) {
            var layer=layerNode[i].artLayers[layerIndex];
            app.activeDocument.activeLayer = layer;

             if (layer.kind == LayerKind.SOLIDFILL) {
                skinColors.open ("a");
                skinColors.write(layer.name + " = " + getAdjustmentLayerColor(app.activeDocument, layer) + ";\n");
                skinColors.close ();
             }
        }
    }
}

getColors(app.activeDocument.layerSets);
```

I hope this is useful for someone, although, as I said, I wish I had noticed earlier!